TypeError: (0 , codecs_1.getBytesCodec) is not a function at ./node_modules/@solana/spl-token-metadata/lib/cjs/state.js
I'm trying to implement the mint functionality with @metaplex-foundations/js library. Here is the source code.
import {
  useConnection,
  useWallet,
} from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { Metaplex, walletAdapterIdentity } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import {
  WalletMultiButton,
} from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui";
const Content = () => {
  const wallet = useWallet();
  const { connection } = useConnection();

  const mintEntryPass = async () => {
    Metaplex.make(connection).use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet));
    // const metaplexPlugin = ;
    // const candyMachineAddress = new PublicKey(
    //   process.env.REACT_APP_CANDY_MACHINE_ID
    // );
    let candyMachine;
    let walletBalance;
  };
  return (
              <div className="flex p-2 justify-center">
                <WalletMultiButton />
                <button onClick={mintEntryPass}>
                  Mint
                </button>
              </div>
  );
};

I have also added a config-override file to solve some issue I had earlier.
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = function override(config) {
  const fallback = config.resolve.fallback || {};
  Object.assign(fallback, {
    crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
    path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
    stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    assert: require.resolve("assert"),
    http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
    https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
    os: require.resolve("os-browserify"),
    url: require.resolve("url"),
    zlib: require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
    "process/browser": require.resolve("process/browser"),
  });
  config.resolve.fallback = fallback;
  config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    }),
  ]);
  return config;
};

The error I'm getting is
React Router caught the following error during render TypeError: (0 , codecs_1.getBytesCodec) is not a function
    at ./node_modules/@solana/spl-token-metadata/lib/cjs/state.js (state.ts:6:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at ./node_modules/@solana/spl-token-metadata/lib/cjs/index.js (index.ts:4:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at ./node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/node_modules/@solana/spl-token/lib/cjs/extensions/tokenMetadata/actions.js (actions.ts:4:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1) 

I can only try minting once the metaplex connection is established. I'm fairly new to solana and could really use some help on this.
